# How do you un-track a medal in Battlefield 1

Tags: battlefield-1

In Battlefield 1 you can track medals. If you completed three challenges within in a given time you are awarded the medal. However, it seems that I cannot turn off this tracking. This is annoying because I want to play some good ol' Team Deathmatch but the game is tracking my progress for a highly objective-oriented play style (repair vehicles, shoot down vehicles) and the clock is ticking.

So even if I don't want to complete challenges, it seems that I am forced to do so if I don't want to lose a chance to get that medal in the future.

Am I overlooking something? I can select another medal but I cannot un-track ALL medals.

Answer (score 1):

The First medal in the list is automatically tracked at the start of every week, and you cannot stop tracking medals. You can however, completely ignore the medal and continue to do whatever you want. Medals are completely optional.

Answer (score 0):

The medals you are tracking are weekly. They reset on sunday night and you will be able to track another 5 medals the following week. Your progress on incomplete medals will be lost on the reset.

Hence, you are not forced to play the medals. You can simply ignore them and play them the next time they are part of the weekly medal collection.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about medal progress being reset; as long as you've fully completed an objective, it appears to remember that when the medal comes around again. Partial progress on objectives is reset however.

Comment: I've been trying to get the assault medal for the last two weeks and every week I had to restart at "Get 10 Kills with Sidearms". So from my experience it resets the complete progress.  On the other hand, medals which I previously did not complete but that didn't yet got added to the weekly set again, still show the incomplete state under Soldier => Medals

Comment: @Cooper Medals are slightly bugged, Mostly, you can select one while in a match from the menu, and it works as expected, but between matches, it seems to not always be this weeks medals, but sometimes will show last weeks, including its progress. Sometimes it will even show it as completed if I actually completed it before. I don't know if the Winter patch fixed it, but I didn't see it in the patch notes, though I could have missed it.